# Fairy Tail Ep. 326 song name

Tags: music, fairy-tail

What is the name of that song in episode 326 when Achnologia had them trapped? The song played when Cobra says he can't die yet because he has friends of his own too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this one: [Natsu's Resolve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml-EvBnNLoE)

They haven't released the OST collection with this one so you'll have to wait for a good quality version.